# Translate jquery tabless

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to translate the tabless, but when I put the translation code:

```
<script type = "text / javascript"
src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Portuguese-Brasil.json"> </script>

"language": {
                "url": "Portuguese-Brasil.lang"
            }
```

The buttons disappear, I believe I don't know where to put the translation part, can someone help me?

follows the complete code:

```
   jQuery(function($) {
  var table = $('# example').DataTable({

    lengthChange: false,
    buttons: ['colvis', 'print', 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'],

    responsive: {
      details: {
        type: 'column',
        target: 'tr'
      }
    },

    columnDefs: [{
      className: 'control',
      orderable: false,
      targets: 0
    }],
    order: [1, 'asc']
  });

  table.buttons().container().appendTo('# example_wrapper .col-md-6: eq (0)');

  language: {
    url: "Portuguese-Brasil.lang"
  };

});
```

Comment: You seem to have a lot of extra spaces where they shouldn't be.   The snippet auto-tidy has removed a lot of them, but this is still an issue: `$('# example')` (should be `$('#example')`) - can you confirm that your issues aren't just because you have `$("#<space>` ?

Comment: You need to put the `language:` part *inside* the `DataTabe({` bit - eg next to `buttons:` with a comm